# row and columns with 1 element

Tags: html, css, quasar-framework, quasar

For the example given here:
https://quasar.dev/layout/grid/gutter#pros-cons-and-how-to-workaround-problems-q-gutter-size-vs-q-col-gutter-size
May I know

1. What's the functions of row and column in the example as we only have 1 item within?
2. Why using row and overflow-auto can solve the gutter-size issue?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### First point

The basic code is:

```css
.column, .flex, .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.column {
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

So for those example it does not make much sens but there is also `offset-1` and `.col-3` and for this, the `.row` is needed (there is also a longer block):

```css
@media (min-width: 0)
.row>.offset-1, .row>.offset-xs-1 {
    margin-left: 8.3333%;
}
@media (min-width: 0)
.row>.col-3, .row>.col-xs-3 {
    height: auto;
    width: 25%;
}
```

I don't know why they did it this way... as they are also able to set `col-x` normaly (except to increate priority):

```css
.col-0, .col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-auto, .col-xs-0, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-auto {
    flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

### Second point

`overflow-auto` is just gonna hide the margin of the its children so instead of having margin on parent, it will be on child.